# replace specific array value with another array values in php

Tags: php, arrays, replace

My 1st array values are

```
Array ( 
[0] => abc 
[1] => xyz 
[2] => Other 
[3] => Other 
[4] => pqr )
```

when array contains value as `Other`, I want to replace that with the below array.

```
Array ( 
[0] => lmnsa 
[1] => asda )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code in your question.

Comment: I am new to PHP and stuck on this part, so need experts helps

Comment: The community does not write the code for you. You write code, and when you are stuck and it does not work, you post that code, and then the community tries to help.

Comment: Due to the incomplete [mcve], this question is Unclear and has led to answers which perform different tasks and divergent output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what result are you looking for.

If you want to just replace elements with value 'Other' with some different value:

```
$newValue = 'New value instead of Other';
// $newValue = ['abc' 'def']; <-- if you want to replace string by an array. It wasn't unclear what you expect to achieve from the question.

$array = ['a', 'b', 'Other', 'c', 'Other', 'd'];
foreach ($array as $idx => $element) {
    if ($element === 'Other') {
        $array[$idx] = $newValue;
    }
}
```

Or if you have an array of replacements, which must gradually replace all 'Other' values:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'Other', 'c', 'Other', 'd'];
$replacements = ['New Value 1', 'New Value 2'];

$replacementIdx = 0;
foreach ($array as $idx => $element) {
    // Always check if you were not run out of replacement values
    if (!isset($replacements[$replacementIdx])) {
        break;
    }

    if ($element === 'Other') {
        $array[$idx] = $replacements[$replacementIdx++];
    }
}
```

Instead of using foreach `($array as $key => $value)` you may also try to replace elements by reference (see RiggsFolly answer)

Answer (score 1):

First loop over the array1 and test for the value `'Other'`, if found replace the value with your `array2`

**Note** the use of `&$a` to make the `$a` from the foreach loop a reference, so that it can be used to replace the original array occurance and not a copy of the array which woudl have been the result without the use of the `&`

```
$array1 = Array ( "abc","xyz","Other", "Other", "pqr" );
$array2 = Array ( "lmnsa", "asda" );

foreach ($array1 as &$a) {
    if ( $a == 'Other') {
        $a = $array2;
    }
}
print_r($array1);
```

The RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => xyz
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lmnsa
            [1] => asda
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => lmnsa
            [1] => asda
        )

    [4] => pqr
)
```

Comment: Please vote this question as Unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your request what Yamingue stated is correct. You may need to clarify what you want. Are you attempting to say if the indexed value of the array initial array is 2 and its value is "Other" to replace it with it with the equivalent value of another array with the same index number?

Its been a while since ive done php buy lets give this a go.

```
$array1 = Array ( 
0 => "abc"
1 => "xyz" 
2 => "Other" 
3 => "Other" 
4 => "pqr" );

    $array2 = Array ( 
    0 => "lmnsa"
    1 => "asda" 
    2 => "thg"
    3 => "ris"
    4 => "slrn");

    Foreach($array1 as $arr1key => $arr1val) {
    If($arr1val == "Other"){
    $array1[$arr1key] = $array2[$arr1key];
    }
    }
```

You may need to unset the values however as i said been a while for me. Nowbif you want to embed the 2nd array into the value of the first array where it currently says other thats another story, each language is a little different on multidimensional and nested arrays so i cant speak to it.

Answer (score -2):

there are several ways to do it as needed. the first is to replace it with another array like this

`

```
$array1 = Array ( 
0 => "abc"
1 => "xyz" 
2 => "Other" 
3 => "Other" 
4 => "pqr" );

$array2 = Array ( 
0 => "lmnsa"
1 => "asda" );

$array1 = $array2
```

`

Comment: the solution provided by you is replacing whole array with 2nd one. I just want to replace particular values when there is "Other".